# Vector problem with plane flying north and wind northeast

Tags: vectors

"A small plane wishes to fly due north at 200 mph (as seen from the ground), in a
wind blowing from the northeast at 50 mph. Tell with what vector velocity in the air it
should travel (give the i j-components)."
Here's my intuition about this problem: my idea initially was to express both of them with vectors with ij components, and then add them. Thus I will get a new vector and that's the direction the plane will travel to, and I will find angle of that vectors with respect to north, and that's the angle plane should travel to offset the wind.
Is this correct approach?

Comment: You are close.  You want to subtract the wind vector from the desired direction vector to get the vector for the course.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2240103/265466 from the handy list of related questions at right.