# I dont understand why how this vector was calculated, is't i+j=v?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

The question from this [Vectors Word Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240103/vectors-word-problem) link.

> A small plane wishes to fly  ℎ at 200 ℎ (as seen from the ground), in a wind blowing from the ℎ at 50 ℎ. Tell with what   in the air it should travel (give the  −).

I dont know how he come up with $\vec{w}=−50(i+j)\div \sqrt2$, from my understanding, $\vec{w}=(-\vec{i}-\vec{j})*50$, since $\vec{i}+\vec{j}$ is 45 degree already.

[image]

========= update ==========

Thank you guy for answering my question, I'm slowly getting some intuition about this vector system. I think the key to understanding my question is the **magnitude**, we have to project wind speed to this vector system by using unit vectors $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$. My current understanding is:
$$\vec{w}=(\vec{i}+\vec{j})\times direction \times magnitude \\
= -(\vec{i}+\vec{j}) \times magnitude \\
then, magnitude= \frac{50}{\sqrt{2}} \\
so, \vec{w}=-(\vec{i}+\vec{j}) \times \frac{50}{\sqrt{2}}\\$$

Comment: The divided by $\sqrt2$ is to make the magnitude of the vector equal to 1. The vector -i-j is supposed to _only_ show the direction and NOT add any extra magnitude to the velocity vector. Just multiplying with -i-j would make the velocity vector have magnitude $50\sqrt2$, while it should be 50 only.

Comment: The answer at the end of that link hasn't been edited since 2017, and it doesn't use $i-j$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, this is like transforming a coordinate system to another? wind speed is in another coord system and we are building that system with $\vec{i}$ and $\vec{j}$, correct?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean. @Yiffany we are just expressing the wind velocity and the resultant velocity (at which it wants to fly) in vector form (assuming the axes along NS and EW) and solve the problem. If you still don’t understand, you are more than welcome to ask.

Comment: Do you know trigonometry? Do you know that $\cos 45^\circ=\sin 45^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$? **That** is where the $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator comes from. Namely, if the magnitude of the wind velocity is $50$, then the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the velocity vector are $-50\cos 45^\circ$ and $-50\sin 45^\circ$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, updated question, does it looks correct?

Comment: It is not totally wrong as such, but it is definitely inaccurate. I would prefer changing the following: (1) When you mention direction, you evidently  mean the plus or minus sign. I would suggest you change direction to mean the UNIT vector (keep in mind, UNIT vector). So the direction would be $-\dfrac{\hat i+\hat j}{\sqrt2}$. (Another example: if the wind blew in direction of $2\hat i+3\hat j$, then the direction would be $\dfrac{2\hat i+3\hat j}{\sqrt5}$). (2) The magnitude of wind velocity is $50$, not $\dfrac{50}{\sqrt2}$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator, thanks, perfectly understand!!!

Comment: Corrigendum: I mistyped. The $\sqrt5$ in my previous comment should be $\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\hi{\hat i}
\newcommand\hj{\hat j}
$
$\hi$ and $\hj$ are unit vectors with length 1, but $-\hi-\hj$ is not a unit vector, it has length $\sqrt{(-\hi-\hj)\cdot(-\hi-\hj)}=\sqrt{\hi^2+\hj^2}=\sqrt2$ so if you take $50\times(-\hi-\hj)$ you get a vector with length $50\times\sqrt2\approx 70$ which doesn't represent the wind correctly. You need to normalise the length of $-\hi-\hj$ so that it is one.

Alternatively you can see this by rotating $\hi$ anticlockwise by $180+45^\circ$, with $\sin(180+45)^\circ=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$ and $\cos(180+45)^\circ=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

For the other part of your question, by the usual definitions a wind from the northeast should be in the direction $-\hi-\hj$ as you suggest. Clicking through to the link, it's another question on this site with [an answer which is in the same direction as yours](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2240159/190784).

Comment: Ahhh I see, thank you!!!! But i dont understand that rotation part, can you explain bit?

Comment: It should say rotating $\hi$ there.